# installing mongodb using docker

Tags: docker

I am installing mongodb on linux mint (Tina) (Ubuntu 18.0.4) using Docker.   I am unsure  what  version  should I install. I see available  tags  here  https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/     Because   my  linux  version is  18.04 Bionic, I guess  I should  use Mongo Bionic  rather  than Xenial  However, I see the tag names  as -

4.1.13-bionic, 4.1-bionic, unstable-bionic

Is  it  an unstable  release ?  What  tag  should I use in  the following command ?

> docker pull mongo:4.1.13-bionic or 4.1-bionic or  something else

If  I  do  not  give a tag, I get  Mongo 4.0.11  However  I don't  see  any  tag 4.0.11-bionic  in the list.  Is it  pulling  4.0.11 Bionic  or  Xenial ?

What is simple tag  vs  shared tag ?

If an image  does not have  suffix  Xenial or Bionic (e.g.  4.0.11) then is it valid for  both  Xenial (Ubuntu 16)  and  Bionic (Ubuntu 18 ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; You can pick any image. Not necessarily matching your host OS.

I guess ubuntu 18.04 is the host OS (the OS running the docker service). 
The image specified in dockerhub is the base docker image for the container and has nothing to do with your host OS.

It only matters if you want to extend the image and/or care about its size.